# Working with external hardware while running OS with Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, virtualization

I installed Debian on Oracle VirtualBox(Running on Windows 10), but Debian is not detecting my external GSM modem connected through the USB port. But when I installed Debian without any virtualization, it detects the GSM modem. Is there anyway to getting Debian to detect my GSM modem while using Oracle VirtualBox? Or any other virtualization technology I can use which enabled me to use external GSM modem with Debian?

Comment: As you passing through the device?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek not sure what you mean. It's the first time I am using virtualization technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *ought* to work.

As per the instructions - on a linux box you may need certain prerequisite packages and to add yourself to  the vmusers group. You will also want to the add vbox extention pack as prompted for any platform

You'd also need to passthrough the device [image]

By rightclicking on the USB icon and selecting the device

If you want to always passthrough this device add a USB filter under the VM settings.